# Problems over an array of integers whose solution is small-in-size and best-known algorithm runs slower than linear?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

> Problems over an array of integers whose solution is small-in-size and best-known algorithm runs slower than linear?

I'm conduction a project, where it would be nice to include a problem where the problem instance is a list of integers and solution is small-in-size, e.g., a single integer. The best-known algorithm for the problem should run slower than linear-time, e.g., n*log(n) or n^2.

I've considered (integer) square-root, extended Euclidean algorithm, etc., but they all run in logarithmic time, which make them unsuitable for the project.

Any ideas?

Comment: Almost anything? O(n) is how long it takes to read the input, and there aren't many problems you can solve without having to read all the input in the worst case, especially for an unsorted array.

Comment: Interpret the input as a square matrix and [compute the permanent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_the_permanent).

Comment: [3SUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM) would be a simple candidate that might feel less cheaty.

Comment: Thank you! I like 3SUM - do you know of a real world application of this algorithm?